# How to split sequences and unpivot this table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

There's a task. I need to transpose this table:

```
    id            value
    1001          param1='afvr';param2='ghx';param3='';...;paramN='zfdf'
    1002          param1='arthr';param2='reger';param3='';....;paramM='zehe'
    1003          param1='qwer';param2='geiew';param3='';...;paramX='qweio'
    ......        ......
    2001          param1='pawoe';param2='eug';param3='';.....;paramn='mds'
```

into this:

```
    id                param1      param1   param3    paramN
    1001              'afvr'      'ghx'    null      'zfdf'
    1002              'arthr'     'reger'  null      'zehe'
    1003              'qwer'      'geiew'  null      'qweio'
    ......            ......
    2001              'pawoe'     'eug'    null      'mds'
```

and this:

```
    id                value
    1001              'afvr'
    1001              'ghx'
    1001               null
    1001              'zfdf'
    1002              'arthr'
    1002              'reger'
    1002               null
    1002              'zehe'
    1003              'qwer'
    1003              'geiew'
    1003               null
    1003              'qweio'
    ......            ......
    2001              'pawoe'
    2001              'eug'
    2001               null
    2001              'mds'
```

Using SQL and regular expressions. Although I understand that I should use loops, I don't get it. Is there a way to do it using Oracle?

Comment: Oracle has another tool, Java, in which I believe it might be easier to handle this data problem.  Databases don't handle exploding strings very well; they were not designed for this.

Comment: There are many ways to split symbol-separated strings into component tokens in plain SQL (much faster than using procedures or Java). So the second table is easy to do, although it seems to lose some information; you should also have a column for the ordinal number ("param number" comparing to your table). Then the transposing (PIVOTING) can be done too, but how to do that - and what tools you need - depends on prior knowledge of the number of parameters. If that may be variable and not known beforehand, that part can't be done in plain SQL.

Comment: Do you actually need the second table, or are you just showing that as a staging point on the way to the final third result? And do you need to know which parm number each value originally had - as mathguy pointed out you don't show that being retained.

Comment: Also, when the value is `'afvr'` you seem to want to extract a string of length 6, beginning and ending in single-quote (as part of the string!) but when the value is `''` you extract `NULL`. That is inconsistent; I assume in the first case you want to extract the four-character string `afvr` - right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only trying to get to the final result shown in your third table, and don't actually need the intermediate view of the data, you could treat the value as parameters in a dummy XML node, and then use XMLTable to extract all of the parameter values:

```
select yt.id, x.value
from your_table yt
cross join xmltable('/tmp/@*'
  passing xmltype('<tmp ' || translate(value, ';', ' ') || ' />')
  columns value varchar2(30) path '.'
) x;
```

Quick demo with a CTE supplying the partial sample data from your question, plus another row to demonstrate a couple of scenarios raised in comments:

```
with your_table (id, value) as (
  select 1001, q'[param1='afvr';param2='ghx';param3='';paramN='zfdf']' from dual
  union all select 1002, q'[param1='arthr';param2='reger';param3='';paramM='zehe']' from dual
  union all select 1003, q'[param1='qwer';param2='geiew';param3='';paramX='qweio']' from dual
  union all select 2001, q'[param1='pawoe';param2='eug';param3='';paramn='mds']' from dual
  union all select 2002, q'[param1='abc def';param2='ghi;jkl';param3='m=n']' from dual
)
select yt.id, x.value
from your_table yt
cross join xmltable('/tmp/@*'
  passing xmltype('<tmp ' || translate(value, ';', ' ') || ' />')
  columns value varchar2(30) path '.'
) x;

        ID VALUE                         
---------- ------------------------------
      1001 afvr                          
      1001 ghx                           
      1001                               
      1001 zfdf                          
      1002 arthr                         
      1002 reger                         
      1002                               
      1002 zehe                          
      1003 qwer                          
      1003 geiew                         
      1003                               
      1003 qweio                         
      2001 pawoe                         
      2001 eug                           
      2001                               
      2001 mds                           
      2002 abc def                       
      2002 ghi jkl                       
      2002 m=n                           

19 rows selected.
```

I've guessed the maximum size of the value, adjust the `(30)` if necessary. This converts the semicolon separators to spaces so they are valid in XML; you could also use `replace()`. The bit inside the XMLType constructor ends up as:

```
        ID TMP_VALUE                                                    
---------- -------------------------------------------------------------
      1001 <tmp param1='afvr' param2='ghx' param3='' paramN='zfdf' />   
      1002 <tmp param1='arthr' param2='reger' param3='' paramM='zehe' />
      1003 <tmp param1='qwer' param2='geiew' param3='' paramX='qweio' />
      2001 <tmp param1='pawoe' param2='eug' param3='' paramn='mds' />   
      2002 <tmp param1='abc def' param2='ghi jkl' param3='m=n' />
```

and the XMLTable looks for all the parameters within than dummy `tmp` node, whatever they are called.

If you might have a semicolon *within* a parameter value and not just as a separator between them then you need to be more careful, since that will be lost - as in the second-to-last value above. You can void that with a regular expression, which will be slower (there may well be a better pattern):

```
select yt.id, x.value
from your_table yt
cross join xmltable('/tmp/@*'
  passing xmltype('<tmp ' || regexp_replace(value, q'[';param]', q'[' param]') || ' />')
  columns value varchar2(30) path '.'
) x;

        ID VALUE                         
---------- ------------------------------
...
      2002 abc def                       
      2002 ghi;jkl                       
      2002 m=n
```

You could even convert each parameter to its own node and change the XPath to match, but not sure that gains you anything.

However, the converted string needs to still be less that 4000 bytes in 11g, including the dummy node construction (`<tmp ... />`). That doesn't look likely to be a problem, but if your current table column is 4000 characters (or bytes) and might be completely filled, it's feasible you'd end up with a string that's just too long; in which case you can change the word 'param' to something shorted in the regex version. The actual name is never used.

Comment: Hmm... this brings to mind a possible problem. When you translate ; to space and use space as the splitting character - what if the values (the strings) include spaces? Of course, the same problem exists with ; in the first place; there can be semicolons in the strings, too. With regexp, one has to be more careful which ; are separators (perhaps something like `(';[^;]*?=|$)` as part of the search string for values). Which may still not work if there may be equal signs in the values... :-)

Comment: @mathguy - I'm not using space as a splitting character. The original parameter values remain within their (single-quote) enclosures, and XMLType is fine with that. Unless the value contains a semicolon, which is lost. I've included a regex that preserves semicolon inside the values - though that does still makes assumptions. I'm sure there are better/more robust patterns, it's not a strong area for me.

Comment: Honestly, all those thoughts that came to mind were about my own approach. I didn't think about any of those possible complications. I think I got lucky - when I wrote my solution I also wanted to unwrap the single-quotes from the values, so I am looking, for example, for an = immediately followed by a ' (which shouldn't normally arise in the "value" even if equal signs may). But that was pure luck, not a reflection of careful thinking!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. I changed the input data a bit - the number and name of parameters are all given beforehand. If that is not the case, the "outermost" query will have to be written separately, after the "t" query is run - and if you want to automate the entire process, you will need to write a procedure in PL/SQL (or perhaps in Java or C# - or even in SQL itself, the way I prefer).

```
with
     test_data ( id, value ) as (
       select 1001, q'#param1='afvr';param2='ghx';param3='';paramN='zfdf'#'    from dual union all
       select 1002, q'#param1='arthr';param2='reger';param3='';paramN='zehe'#' from dual union all
       select 1003, q'#param1='qwer';param2='geiew';param3='';paramN='qweio'#' from dual union all
       select 2001, q'#param1='pawoe';param2='eug';param3='';paramN='mds'#'    from dual
     ),
     t ( id, param, token ) as (
       select id, 
              regexp_substr(value, '(;|^)([^=]*?)=', 1, level, null, 2),
              regexp_substr(value, '=''([^;]*?)''(;|$)', 1, level, null, 1)
       from   test_data
       connect by level <= regexp_count(value, '=')
           and prior id = id
           and prior sys_guid() is not null
     )
select * from t
pivot (min(token) for param in ('param1' as param1, 'param2' as param2,
                                'param3' as param3, 'paramN' as paramN))
order by id
;
```

If you just run `t` by itself it will give you the second table. Also, if performance is a problem (it will always be a problem with data in that format), you can avoid `regexp` functions altogether - just write back and we'll show you how it can be done with `substr()`, `instr()` and `translate()` (instead of `regexp_count()`)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to know in advance is maximum number of parameters

---

```
select  id      
       ,regexp_substr (value,'.+?=''(.*?)''',1,1,'',1)  as param1      
       ,regexp_substr (value,'.+?=''(.*?)''',1,2,'',1)  as param2      
       ,regexp_substr (value,'.+?=''(.*?)''',1,3,'',1)  as param3      

from    t
;
```

and

```
select  id
       ,value

from   (select  id      
               ,regexp_substr (value,'.+?=''(.*?)''',1,1,'',1)  as param1      
               ,regexp_substr (value,'.+?=''(.*?)''',1,2,'',1)  as param2      
               ,regexp_substr (value,'.+?=''(.*?)''',1,3,'',1)  as param3      

        from    t
        ) t unpivot exclude nulls (value for col in (param1,param2,param3)) t
;
```

Comment: In this approach, it seems as if one would need to know the maximum number of parameters in advance, even to get the second table. Actually the second table can be derived without knowing the number (or name) of parameters in advance.